# how to filter in kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to know how to filter data out in kendo ui gird.
I'm getting data from db by using JSON.

When I debugger function JsonGetBill in Bill controller,
I can't even debugger anything.
Maybe, KendoGrid didn't try to get data from JsonGetBill.
How can I solve this problem?

Plz, Help me.

```
$('#divBillInfoGrid').kendoGrid({            
        dataSource: {                
            type: "JSON",                
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("JsonGetBill", "Bill")',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "APPLICATION/JSON"
                }
            },
            schema:{
                model:{
                    fields: {
                        BIL_Idx: { type: "number" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
        },
        height: 550,
        filterable: {
            mode: "row"
        },
        pageable: true,
        columns: [

            { field: "BIL_Idx", title: "No", filterable: { cell: { showOperators: false } }, sortable: true, template: '<div class="idx" style="font-size:12px text-align:center;">#=BIL_Idx#<div>' }

        ],

    });    
}
```

Comment: Put $('#divBillInfoGrid').getKendoGrid().dataSource.read(); in your code, execute it and then look your browser developer console to see what happened.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the content.. Where is the filtering problem?

Comment: @Japi, Okay, thank u! : )

Comment: @tede24, I thought it didn't work because of some filtering code....sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Probably like your function says "JsonGetBill " is not an type="Get"??
How else is a Post is not necessary to send data ?

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource

Hope this help

Comment: thank u! I've seen this post a lot for solving my problem. but I could't change my code like this. Maybe I have to study.... Anyway Thank u very much!